# Datadog search by java stacktrace

Tags: java, monitoring, stack-trace, datadog

Anyway, how can I search for all messages(errors) where stacktrace contains specific piece of code? According to datadog documentation it search only by message attribute(it's infered from the json-like object sent to datadog when you log something). Stacktrace is a separate property and I cannot understand how to search it.

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as searching by:

```
@stack_trace:*some_exception*
```

Spaces in multiple words must be escaped as other special characters.

```
@stack_trace:*word\ another_word*
```

More on this [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_explorer/query_syntax/).